# Jsreport Xlsx Column Size

Tags: c#, xlsx, jsreport

I want to set column size based on data length

[image: i generate the xlsx like this]

[image: I want it like this]

where can i set that property?

*Edit:

[here's the code used to generate the xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/806zw.png), recipe is Xlsx

Comment: Don't use links to images. Provide your code or images directly inside the question. You can use this site to create ascii tables: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: I'll respectfully disagree with an issue posting images - they illustrate what you want to do quite well. However, this question needs to show the code that was used to generate the first image, and is also almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Which recipe you use, html-to-xlsx or xlsx?

Comment: I used xlsx recipe

Comment: I don't think xlsx recipe able to do that. (Reference: https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport/issues/597): "Unfortunately, office XML doesn't know "autofit".
The excel on double click just calculates the real height and put a number to the style.

I think it is not possible for us to magically calculate the real width/height as the excel does." by @JanBlaha